# React Navigation - Dynamic Text (translations) needed in drawerNavigator drawerLabels from Redux store

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux, react-navigation

Using react-navigation in a React Native app with Redux, I need to show `drawerLabels` in the `drawerNavigation` dynamically as they change depending on language. I therefore need to access the store and props (eg `this.props.locale`) but can't seem to get it working. Any help appreciated.

I've tried passing `screenProps` from the main parent `appNavigator`, which does have access to the `store` but not sure how to access them inside the `drawerNavigator`.

I don't really want to store the whole navigation in Redux as the docs imply this will not be supported in the future and can be avoided.

My root is `AppNavigator`, my `settingsNavigation` file is as follows.

```
    const BookingsNavigator = createStackNavigator (
    ...
    );

    ...

    const SettingsNavigator = createDrawerNavigator(
        {
            CurrentBookings: {
                screen: BookingsNavigator,
                navigationOptions: {
                    drawerLabel: 'My bookings',
                }
           },
       ...

       },

    );

const AppNavigator = createSwitchNavigator({  
    Bookings: BookingsNavigator,
   // other navigators
});

export default AppNavigator;
```

Comment: Fixed it using this method https://codeburst.io/custom-drawer-using-react-navigation-80abbab489f7

Answer (score 2):

For dynamic language change (in settings screen):

```
static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
    const { params } = navigation.state;
    return {
      title: i18n.t('settings.settings'), // drawer label initialization
      drawerLabel: params && params.DLabel,
      drawerIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
        <Icon name="md-settings" style={{ fontSize: 24, color: tintColor }} />
      ),
    };
  };

  // no need to preset drawer label because we define title in navigationOptions
  // componentWillMount() {
  //   this.props.navigation.setParams({ DLabel: i18n.t('settings.settings') });
  // }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (prevProps.language !== this.props.language) { // redux props from language picker
      // for current screen (drawer item)
      this.props.navigation.setParams({ DLabel: i18n.t('settings.settings') });
      // home screen (drawer item)
      const setHomeLabel = NavigationActions.setParams({
        params: { DLabel: I18n.t('home') },
        key: 'Home',
      });     
      this.props.navigation.dispatch(setHomeLabel);
      // inbox screen (drawer item)
      const setInboxLabel = NavigationActions.setParams({
        params: { DLabel: i18n.t('Inbox') },
        key: 'Inbox',
      });
      this.props.navigation.dispatch(setInboxLabel);
    }
  }
```

How to change the language:

```
  onLanguageChange = (value) => {
    this.props.languageChanged(value); // redux action from language picker
    i18n.locale = value === 0 ? 'ru' : 'en'; // set locale manually
  };
```

In home screen component:

```
static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
    const { params } = navigation.state;
    return {
      title: i18n.t('home'), // drawer label initialization
      drawerLabel: params && params.DLabel,
      drawerIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
        <Icon
          type="Entypo"
          name="wallet"
          style={{ fontSize: 24, color: tintColor }}
        />
      ),
    };
  };
```